# How to extract link from a specific division on a webpage using beautifulsoup

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and a bit confused with my current situation.  Is there a way to extract the link for all the sector from this website(where I circled in red)  From the html inspector, it seems like it is under the "performance-section" class and it is also under the "heading" class.  My idea was to start from the "performance-section" then reach the "a" tag href in the end to get the link.

[image]
[image]

I tried to use the following code but it is giving me "None" as a result.  I stopped here because if I am already getting None before getting the "a" tag, then I think there is no point of keep going.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/goto/markets_sectors/landing.jhtml"
response = requests.get(url)
results_page = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
heading =results_page.find('performance-section',{'class':"heading"})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with your mind game.

#### Problem

You should take another look at the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), because currently you don't even try to select tags, but try a mix of classes - It is also possible, but to learn you should start step by step.

#### Solution to get the `<a>` and its `href`

This will select all `<a>` in `<div>` with class `heading`
that parents are `<div>` with class `performance-section`

```
soup.select('div.performance-section div.heading a')
```

.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/goto/markets_sectors/landing.jhtml"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')

[link['href'] for link in soup.select('div.performance-section div.heading a')]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion and the help!  That worked perfectly and I really need to try to look at the documentation more carefully!